# jQuery parseHTML returns undefined on TITLE tag in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, developer-tools, ie8-browser-mode

When trying to parse the string `<title>Hello</title>` to html by using jquery `parseHTML` function, it return undefined in **IE8**. (I've tested it on Browser/Document Mode in IE devtools)

```js
$.parseHTML("<title>hello</title>")[0].nodeName
```

The above works well on IE9,IE10 by returning `TITLE`. It even got stranger when I found out that it ignores `<title>` tag completely.

```js
$.parseHTML("<title>hello</title><h1>Heading</h1>")[0].nodeName
```

The code above expected to returns `TITLE` but in IE8 it returns `H1`, which shows the bug ignores title tag. I use jquery 1.10.2, I've tested older jquery releases, all had the same issue.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: I assume it's because IE8 doesn't think there isn't a `title` element for it to create. `parseHTML` wraps around native DOM functions, so if it doesn't work, it doesn't work. I'm curious about why you're trying to create a `<title>` element in the first place. You cannot have a `<title>` in your body, it's only valid in the `<head>`, which isn't part of your DOM.

Comment: I'm trying to get the title of the page I got from an ajax request. The request get the whole html, and I need to extract the parts I need.

Comment: I'm currently extending somebody's else code. I think I can achieve my goal by using regular expression. Since I thought others may have been faced with the similar situation, a workaround would be helpful.